# Json array formatting

Tags: json

I am having an issue with this JSON file. I cannot seem to find out what I did wrong. I was told my formatting was incorrect by a friend but cannot seem to find out how I went wrong.

Would anybody be able to point out the flaw in my formatting and explain so I can prevent this from happening on further projects?

http://pastebin.com/nzTrPvMd

This is the pastebin file

Answer (score 1):

The mapping in the middle of the file is weird:

```
{
        "Username":"CENSORED", "CENSORED",
```

A key (like `"Username"`) can only have one value. You appear to be trying to store two here. Mappings look like this:

```
{
    "key": "a value",
    "another key": "another value",
    "number of things": 4,
}
```

Keys must be strings, but values can be any JSON type. You can, for example, have a key point to a list:

```
"Username": ["CENSORED", "CENSORED"]
```

Or a mapping with descriptive keys, if a list isn't appropriate:

```
"Username": {
    "FirstName": "CENSORED",
    "LastName": "CENSORED"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in JSON, **square brackets** [] indicates an array as a list. A JSON list never contains associative keys, here valid examples:

```
["first", "second", "third"]
[{"id":"1"}, {"id", "2"}]
```

**Braces** indicate an array as an object that could contain nothing or N pair of values ("key":"value"). an example:

```
{"id":"1"}
{"name":"john", "age":"12"}
{} (empty object)
```

Follow this easy instruction and you'll make valid JSON every time